# How can I create Java web service (jax-ws) with array or List as a parameter

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I've got a problem with a web service which has an array or List as parameter. Here is example:

```
@WebMethod
public String printList(@WebParam(name = "list") List<String> list) {
    String result = "";
    if(list == null) {
        result = "list is null";
    } else if(list.size() == 0) {
        result = "list is empty";
    } else {
        for(String elem : list) {
            result += elem + " ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I call printList from web service client the result is always "list is empty" The same is when I use array of String. Should I use some additional annotations or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is *perfect*, it seems you are calling it wrong way,

and you can remove second condition directly second else will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I call some other method of the same web service which for example take one String parameter everything works perfectly - passed String (or long, int or whatever) argument is not null nor empty. So I think I call it correctly. Is there a pssibility that I do something wrong in generating web service?

Comment: @Pawel try using SOAP ui once. It seems perfect from server end

Comment: life.java It works with soapui - you are right it must be something at the client side. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The array datatype in a JAX Webservice is not supportive, so you need to use libraries and tools for such a thing...

Comment: The arrays are supported both as a return type and as a web parameter's type when you declare them in your web services but such a web parameter is received as a java.util.List on the client side and the return type becomes YourPrettyObjectArray, calling YourPrettyObjectArray.getItem() returns a java.util.List.